# Capturar datos que estan en foreach en spring

Tags: java, spring

hola tengo un problema es que no se como obtener los datos seleccionados con `checkbox` por fuera del **foreach** en la parte que dice `class="text-left" href="< value=" eliminar_dependencia.htm?id="/>"`.. debe efectuar la función

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="widget-title"> <span class="icon"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
    <h5>Administración Dependencias</h5>
    <a class="text-left" href="<c:url value=" eliminar_dependencia.htm?id="/>"><span class="icon"><i class="icon-trash"></i></span></a>
    <a href="<c:url value=" nueva_dependencia.htm "/>"><span class="icon"><i class="icon-plus"></i></span></a>
  </div>

  <c:forEach items="${depende}" var="dato">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Selec" value="ON" /></td>
      <td>
        <c:out value="${dato.idDependencias}" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <c:out value="${dato.nomDependencia}" />
      </td>
      <td <a href="<c:url value=" eliminar_dependencia.htm?id=${dato.idDependencias} "/>">Eliminar</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción seria agregar un atributo `isSelected` a `dato`

```
public class Dato{
   private boolean isDependencia;
   private String nomDependencia;
   private boolean isSelected;

   //getters and setters

}
```

Y que dicho atributo este bindeado al checkbox

```
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Selec" value="${dato.isSelected}" /></td>
```

Luego,  el backend que captura el request de `eliminar_dependencia.htm` deberia recorrer tu listado al que llamaste `depende` y recuperar los datos cuyo valor para `isSelected` sea `true`

Espero haber interpretado bien la consulta y que te sea de ayuda.